# How to filter only a subset of data while maintain existing records as is in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dremio

[SQL Novice] I have a table that looks like this:

```
id             date
1              2019-01-01
1              2019-01-02
2              2019-03-01
2              2019-05-01
```

I want to only filter the `id` column on  `2` where date is between 2019-04-01 and 2019-05-01 without impacting `id` equals `1`.

The new table should look like this:

```
id             date
1              2019-01-01
1              2019-01-02
2              2019-03-01
```

I tried this:

```
select * from table1 where id =2 and date between 2019-03-01 and 2019-04-01
```

And get this data set:

```
id             date

2              2019-03-01
```

Comment: Put all of your `where` criteria in parentheses and add `or id <> 2` outside of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `or`:

```
where id = 1 or
      (id = 2 and date between '2019-03-01' and '2019-04-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

for your desired result need

```
select * from table1 where  [date] >= '2019-01-01' and [date] <= '2019-03-01'
```

Comment: Added tick marks around your dates and changed to ANSI compliant strings. ;)